# Is it possible to use the time passed in a .transition() .duration() as a variable?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I hope the headline is clear.

Let's say in D3 you have a simple mouseover script -- it could be anything -- that changes the underlying svg object's stroke color. Your code looks like this:

```
d3.select(this.parentNode.appendChild(this)).transition().duration(90)
             .style("stroke-width","2").style("stroke","white");
```

Is it possible to know how far along the duration is in the completion of its cycle?

So for example, let's say the "duration thus far" is assigned to the variable Y. Then we could say something like:

```
d3.select(this.parentNode.appendChild(this)).transition().duration(90)
                 .style("stroke-width","2").style("stroke", function(d,Y){return "rgb(\"" + Y + "255,255\" )"});
```

The result would be for the stroke RGB value to depend on the time until the completion of the duration.

Any ideas?

Comment: What are you trying to do? You know you can just transition color with CSS?

Comment: @Jonathan This would be for a general use case. Of course you can transition color with CSS but D3 has much more functionality than CSS that I would like to utilize.

Comment: I deleted my answer. I didn't realize he was using D3. I think D3 has easing as well though. Easing functions might have access to the duration info. If not you could track it yourself and use it in an easing function.

Comment: @ChristopherWhite Added to clarify this is for D3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are pretty flexible in these things, when using custom functions. Here, you are referring to 'style' attributes, so you might want to look at `styleTween`, like e.g. so:

```
d3.select('#rect1')
   .transition().duration(500)
   .style("stroke-width", "10px")
   .styleTween("stroke", function() {
       return d3.interpolate("green", "red");
    });
```

Alternatively, you can define your custom functions, like:

```
function interpolateGeneric(col1, col2) {
    return function(t) {
        return d3.interpolate(col1, col2)(t);
    };
}
```

Notice here the parameter `t`, which gives you the progress of the transition.

And then:

```
d3.select('#rect2')
    .transition().duration(500)
    .styleTween('stroke', function() {
        return interpolateGeneric('green', 'blue');
   })
   .style("stroke-width", "10px")
```

To modify 'attr', look at `attrTween`.

See e.g. here: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/transition/